# Updating data in database using ajax and php works only on first echoed data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to update database on button click. These are gotten and echoed from database using `php` and i would like to delete these with `ajax`

Below is the php code

```
<?php
        $sql = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM questions");
        $result = $sql->execute();

        while ($row = $result->fetchArray(SQLITE3_ASSOC))
        {
            $quiz_id = $row['quiz_id'];
            $question = $row['question'];
            $answer = $row['answer'];

            echo '<form action="updatequestion.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <tr>
            <td><input style="width: 50%" type="text" name="cid" id="cid" value="'.$quiz_id.'"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="question" id="question" value="'.$question.'"></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="answer" id="answer" value="'.$answer.'"></td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="qupdate" id="qupdate" value="Update"></td>
            </tr>
            </form>';

        }
        ?>
```

The `ajax`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#qupdate').click(function() {
    question = $('#question').val();
    answer = $('#answer').val();
    id = $('#cid').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "updatequestion.php",
        data: "cid="+id+"&question="+question+"&answer="+answer,
        success: function(html){
            if(html = "true")
            {
                $('#qupdate').css("opacity", "1");
            }
            else
            {
                alert("not successful");
            }
        },
        beforeSend: function(){
            $('#qupdate').css("opacity", "0.5");
        }
    });
    return false;
});
});
```

I would like to update a particular question using the ajax code but only the first `echo` data works with the `ajax`.

Answer (score 0):

You have several forms with submit elements, that have the same id. Each page can have only one element with that id. It's a unique identifier. You can use the same class on multiple elements. 
So add class `qupdate` for `submit` element and change `$('#qupdate')` selector to `$('.qupdate')`. If you need an id attribute for submit, you can make it unique by adding some additional unique number, for example `id="qupdate-'.$quiz_id.'"`

Comment: When i use the `class`, all `echo` data update when i click on one alone. When is use the `id` with unique number, The `ajax` is not called.

Comment: Which selector for the click event in this case?